# Issue with Wordpress Dashboard Alert for Staging Site

Tags: wordpress, staging

My issue is with an alert on the Wordpress Dashboard saying that `Note: This is a staging site` which it's not - or at least it shouldn't be, I never put this site into staging.

[image]

My client's site is hosted on goDaddy and the original staging site was transferred from managed wordpress hosting to the cPanel.  I moved the site via FTP and am not sure how to get rid of this warning and would love any help in the right direction.

I have tried using Health Check and disabling all plugins and changing the theme to default but the alert still persists.

Please let me know if you need more details.

The site is [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

The error was in the goDaddy plugin.

```
go to your file manager or ftp to your site
open gd_config.php
change define( 'GD_STAGING_SITE', true);
to
define( 'GD_STAGING_SITE', false);
```

Thanks to this [article](https://uk.godaddy.com/community/Building-and-Managing-a-Website/Manual-Migration-of-STAGING-site-to-PRODUCTION-issues/m-p/100664/thread-id/14126)